# Alternative to innerTheme when we want to have different primaryTypographyProps

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a component which has a List customized with ListeItems and Icons and Buttons. I want to use this component in 2 different places. In one place, I set the MuiListItemTextTypography props this way..

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
.
.
.
typography: {
    useNextVariants: true
    body1: {
      fontSize: '14px'
    }
  },
props: {
    MuiListItemText: {
      primaryTypographyProps: {
        variant: "body1"
      },
      secondaryTypographyProps: {
        variant: "body2"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

But a second component wants the font size to be 12 px, so I did it this way

```
const innerTheme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    body1: {
      fontSize: '12px'
    }
  },
  props: {
    MuiListItemText: {
      primaryTypographyProps: {
        variant: "body1"
      },
      secondaryTypographyProps: {
        variant: "body1"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

and wrapped the second component in new Theme

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={innerTheme}>
   <ListItems itemsList={secondItem}/>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

It works fine, but the drawback is that I lose all the styles set in main theme when I wrap it in an inner theme

How can I do this so that I do not lose all that in the first theme.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good example of how to do this here: [Nesting the Theme](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/#nesting-the-theme)

`MuiThemeProvider` accepts a function, so you can redefine `innerTheme` as:

```
const innerTheme = {
  typography: {
    body1: {
      fontSize: '12px'
    }
  },
  props: {
    MuiListItemText: {
      primaryTypographyProps: {
        variant: "body1"
      },
      secondaryTypographyProps: {
        variant: "body1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then change your markup to:

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme => createMuiTheme({...theme, ...innerTheme})}>
  <ListItems itemsList={secondItem}/>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```